# moon light effect in cycles are not working?

Tags: lighting

im using cycles and following cgmatters tutorial and the transition is weird help
[image]
[image]

Comment: help plz i dont know whats going on

Comment: can you show the model in the editor?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: ook i put it in

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6718" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6718/)